Using VSCode shortcuts for navigation with the vim extension in normal mode makes the cursor jump back upon movement
In my VSCode installation, I am using the vim extension.
When I am in vim's normal mode, I sometimes use VSCode shortcuts to move around in the code. For example, I use:

Go to definition (mapped to F3 in my configuration)
Next Problem (mapped to F8 in my configuration)

This seems to move the cursor to the location specified by the shortcut, as expected.
If I use these shortcuts with vim in normal mode, then as soon as I do a vim action aftwards, such as moving the cursor with hjkl, or going into insert mode with i, the cursor jumps back to my last location, which is not the behavior I expect. I could not figure out why this happens and it's driving me nuts.
This does not happen if vim is in insert mode and I use the shortcut.
Any idea if there's a way to get it to work the way I expect?
